# Home screen wallpaper not covering entire screen

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm using ios 9 and ipad pro 9.7 inch. When I set the homepage wallpaper the bottom horizontal area reserved for icons is not using the wallpaper, instead it uses a grey background :

[image]

On the lock screen the images utilizes whole screen.

Can the wallpaper for home screen be set so it incorporates the menu space at bottom of screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intended behavior and it cannot be changed. The bottom row takes on a color derived from the background itself (similar to iTunes when you expand an album).

Generally, that row will be filled with icons. Seeing it with a special background helps differentiate those apps which will show up on every page.